# IIS7 website deployment stopping file sharing?

Tags: windows, iis, iis-7, windows-xp, fileshare

I have several windows shares hosted on a PC running Win7x64.  This machine is also hosting a basic website via IIS7.  Whenever I deploy a new copy of the website to IIS any WinXP users connected to the shares on that machine get disconected.

After some period of time (20mins or so) the shares all start working again.

This only seems to affect WinXP clients, with them recieving this error message described here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/890413.

The resolution provided by Microsoft works, but it means that everything I deploy a new copy of the website all of my users have to go through this hassle.

Any IIS experts out there know what is happening, or how to resolve this?

Thanks